# Is anyone (institution, city, country, individual ...) testing the usage of salt coated repiratory masks?

Tags: covid-19, salt, face-mask-respirator

I'm referring to an article published in Nature: [Universal and reusable virus deactivation system for respiratory protection](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep39956). It has had some media coverage over the past few months, e.g. https://www.businessinsider.de/international/mask-coated-in-salt-neutralizes-viruses-like-coronavirus-2020-2/?r=US&IR=T, https://www.intelligentliving.co/salty-coating-masks-kills-coronavirus/

I'm asking myself if it is feasible to use the salt coating for everyday masks as well. Their usage is surging around the world and table salt is also widely available. Hyo-Jick Choi, one of the researchers behind the Nature article tries to work with the industry to create salt coated masks. But he expects a time horizon of roughly 18 months. This would be good for upcoming pandemics. Still I'm wondering if there is someone (e.g. a city, hospital, ...) trying to apply salt coating to existing masks. I mean the resources spent on this are not very expensive and the potential upside is huge.

Comment: It says the process is patented.

Comment: I'm no patent lawyer but doesn't this only prohibit commercial use without the patent holder's consent? So a hospital would still be free to coat their masks in saturated NaCl solution. Besides the only patent I can find for masks are roughly10 years older... WO2007120509A2, WO2008009651A1 and refer to acids/bases and their salts. Edit: This seems to be the patent CA3033013A1